# How do I display the result of a SendHTTRequest Activity?

Tags: workflow

I have a `SendHTTPRequest` activity in an Elsa Workflow and it executes correctly, but the response doesn't get displayed even though I selected `Read Content`. The page is still empty. Why isn't it showing the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any documentation on `SendHTTPRequest` but after looking at the source code and some trial and error, I was able to get the response to show by adding a `WriteHTTPResponse` after the `SendHTTPRequest`. The `SendHTTPRequest` also needed some additional configuration:

- Add values in the `Supported Status Codes` section. This creates the different flow paths after execution.
- Give it a `Name` (e.g. `GetHTTP`) so you can get access to the response in `WriteHTTPResponse`.

Now drag the status code path to `WriteHTTPRequest` so it will execute that activity on a 200. In the `Content` section you can then use an expression to output the response.

E.g. `GetHTTP.Response.Content` and select `JavaScript` from the dropdown.

[image]